# Maximum power transfer and maximizing the load

Tags: power-transfer

[image: circuit system]

[image: equation]

Hello, I would like to ask how to find the source's reactive power
Also, the reactive power consumed by R1 and Rload and the input power factor of the resistors
given that Rload is 10 ohms.

What value maximizes the power transferred to the load?

The problem is here, while trying to find the total impedance, there are both real and imaginary values in the numerator and denominator, which makes the calculations so hard to me.
The voltage source has three trigonometric functions which makes me think there can be 3 sources but I have never encountered more than one AC source, so I am not sure what to do in the calculations. How can you combine different frequencies? I would appreciate your help.